# how can i scroll text on a python tk/tinker Label?

Tags: python, scroll, tkinter, scrollbar, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to add a simple log output to a tk window/frame.

So far i only found how to (easily) add a vertical scrollbar on `canvas`, entry lists and `text` (which is a fullblown text editor and has no `textvariable` linking support)

The `Label` can't be attached to a `scrollbar` (easily) because it lacks the `yview` attribute.

```
#my naive attempt:...
self.lbl_log = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=10, textvariable=self.string_log)
self.lbl_log.pack(side="top")
self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.lbl_log.yview)
self.lbl_log.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
```

> AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'yview'

is there any easy and convenient way to scroll a label widget with several lines in python tk? I don't necessarily have to use a `Label` i just like it because it is simple and has the `textvariable` convenience) so i'm open to alternative widgets for this problem.

Comment: It's just what it says on the tin: `Label` objects don't have a `yview` and are therefore not scrollable. You'll have to cobble something together with scrollable widgets. Keep in mind that `Label` isn't intended to display anything more than a label - `Message` is more suited to larger blocks of text. If it's so big that it needs to scroll, try a `Text` object (you can disable it to prevent modification if you want).

Comment: You could do the text wrapping yourself. Just take a character off the front of string and put it on the end of the string and set the text again. It may have a side effect that it will appear to go faster and slower due to the difference in character widths. It should work though.

Comment: Hacking together an emulated scrollbar to shoehorn an inappropriate widget into the program will cause pain. I highly recommend using a `Text` widget as @Bryan and I are suggesting, as it's intended for larger blocks of text and it's compatible with `Scrollbar`.

Comment: So, absolutely no combination of easy scroll + content from a variable?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an easy way to scroll a label. If you need to scroll multiple lines, a label is the wrong choice of widget. If you need to scroll multiple lines of text, the text widget is the proper widget.